# Find the coordinates of the cursor on iOS devices using XCtest

Tags: ios, xctest

I'm trying to find the `x` and `y` coordinates of the current cursor position on a iOS device. Assume the keyboard to be up. I'm using XCUItest framework. Below is a screenshot of the device.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Even with Xcode 11.4.1 in XCUITest I can't handle the keyboard position on tap().